# GWT Animate Widget Swap

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.3

I am using GWT 2.3 and have a FlowPanel with a number of child Widgets.  Part of my application invloves the swapping of elements in this FlowPanel, which I have implemented using insert(int, Widget).  This functionally works well, but needs some visual sugar.  Does anyone know of a way to animate the swapping of the Widgets?  Preferably, I would rather not replace the FlowPanel with an absolute panel to accomplish this.

Comment: Can you maybe clarify for me what you mean by "swap"? Do you want to replace one widget with another widget that is not added to the FlowPanel or do you want to swap the postion of a widget in the FlowPanel with another widget in the FlowPanel?

Comment: I am swapping the positions of two widgets already added to the flow panel.  I implemented the swap routine by reinserting each widget into the FlowPanel at the other's original index.

Comment: Custom FadeIn/FadeOut animations for the two widgets ? Maybe not the most appropriate but better than nothing...

Comment: have you found a solution since?